# How can I use parameters within a measure?

Tags: parameters, powerbi, dax, measure

I am trying to create two numeric range parameters (P1 and P2), and then use them as variables within a measure to create a calculation. As a start, I would like to sum them up. So, the measure should return [the value of P1] + [the value of P2].

After creating my two parameters in a tab (which are dynamically adjustable by slicers), I created a measure with the following logic:

NewMeasure =
VAR P1val = 'P1'[P1 Value]
VAR P2val = 'P2'[P2 Value]

RETURN P1val + P2val

If the P1 value = 4 and P2 value = 5, the measure should return 9. But it returns blank.

Comment: That syntax should work. Is your measure on another tab to the slicers? If you have, you need to sync your slicers to the other tab

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct approach should be to apply an aggregation on the values to pick the selected one, e.g.:

```
NewMeasure = 
VAR P1val = SELECTEDVALUE ( 'P1'[P1 Value] )
VAR P2val = SELECTEDVALUE ( 'P2'[P2 Value] )
RETURN 
  P1val + P2val
```

Comment: If they are using a numeric range parameter(s), the value measure created already has SELECTEDVALUE added to it

Comment: The notation `'P1'[P1 Value]` is not how you should reference measures. Any experienced Power BI developer will tell you that this is a column reference.

Comment: The notation is '<Table>'[<Object>] (Fully qualified name of the item), measures can just be declared as [<measure>], or  '<Table>'[<measure>]  in this case it is a measure. Please refer to the the MS DAX Syntax https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/dax-syntax-reference.

Comment: I am fully aware of this - but measures **should** be written out without the table name, for obvious reasons. There is literally no way for you to know whether `'P1'[Value]` refers to a measure or a column.

Answer (score 0):

The above syntax should work, if you have created some numeric range parameters using the Modelling/New Parameter option. As noted in my comment it will return a blank if the parameter slicers are on another page to where the measure is placed, if the slicer are not synchronized.

In this example I have recreated your basic solution:

[image]

Two parameter slicers have been created, called 'Parameter' and 'Parameter 2', and contains two objects automatically create. The table of the integer range, and the measure that takes the selected value from the slicer.
The table is created using a generate series uses the syntax of:

```
Parameter = GENERATESERIES(0, 20, 1)
```

Which creates a series from 0 to 20 in increments of 1.
The 'Parameter Value' is a measure, that is created with the syntax of:

```
Parameter Value = SELECTEDVALUE('Parameter'[Parameter])
```

So using your code as a base for the summing of the two parameters values:
With P1 = 4 and P2 = 5:

```
New Measure = VAR p1 = 'Parameter'[Parameter Value]
VAR p2 = 'Parameter 2'[Parameter Value 2]
RETURN p1 + p2
```

Yields the result of 9
[image]

In the case if it retuning blank, as mentioned in my comment, if your measure is on a separate page the slicer context isn't passed to that page, and you will have to use the option of 'synchronize Slicers' to apply slicers from one page to the others.

[image]

If you select the slicer object and in this case tick the Page 2 options, then the slicer will propagate to the page the measure is on. You can also choose to show the slicers on the other page or not in the Sync Slicers option.
Example PBIX file 'SO_Question_76424090.pbix' is [here](https://github.com/mrjonlunn/PowerBIExampleFiles/tree/master)